# Java/Android: Parsing XML to get all the xml in a certain tag

Tags: java, android, xml, string, parsing

I'm programming in java (and ultimately in Android) and I have a set up like this

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>stuff</C>
     <D>
       <E>other stuff</E>
       <F>more stuff</F>
     </D>
  </B>

  <B>
    <C>stuff</C>
  </B>

   <B>
     <C>some stuff</C>
     <D>
        <E>basic stuff</E>
        <F>even more stuff</F>
     </D>
  </B>
</A>
```

I want to parse it so that we get (amongst other things which I've already coded) all the things in both D's so we'd get Strings that look like

```
<E>other stuff</E>
<F>more stuff</F>
```

an empty string ("") and

```
<E>basic stuff</E>
<F>even more stuff</F>
```

The parser I've been using stops as soon as it hits a lesser than symbol '<', so it's been giving me nothing. Is there a way to parse it the way I described in Java?

EDIT: I just converted it to a String and used regular expressions.

Comment: Any decent parser should be able to do this for you with little to no effort, bar maybe getting the empty string in the middle, how does your code look?

Comment: TheList = firstClientElement.getElementsByTagName("D");
TheElement = (Element) TheList.item(0);
     
if (TheList.item(0) != null) {
TheList = TheElement.getChildNodes();
output = TheList.item(0).getNodeValue();
} 
I couldn't find any examples of how to get back XML in a tag as a string.

Answer (score 0):

To turn parsed XML back into a string, you can use a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`. I've attached code which parses your example XML and prints all `D` elements to the console - I think you'll be able to turn this into what you want :)

```
// The below is simply to create a document to test the code with
String xml = "<A><B><C>stuff</C><D><E>other stuff</E><F>more stuff</F></D></B><B><C>stuff</C></B><B><C>some stuff</C><D><E>basic stuff</E><F>even more stuff</F></D></B></A>";

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource docSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(docSource);
// The above is simply to create a document to test the code with

// Transformer takes a DOMSource pointed at a Node and outputs it as text
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
// Add new lines for every element
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
// Skip the <? xml ... ?> prolog
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

NodeList elements = document.getElementsByTagName("D");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult res = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource();
for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) elements.item(i);
    source.setNode(element);
    // Write the current element to the stringwriter via the streamresult
    transformer.transform(source, res); 
}
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

If you only want the contents of the elements, you can replace the for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) elements.item(i);
    NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
        Node childNode = childNodes.item(j);
        source.setNode(childNode);
        transformer.transform(source, res);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps, now I just gotta figure out how some of the code works. I didn't need the D's at the end but I can parse those out if I can't figure out how to remove them as is.

Comment: Actually I may need something else because you could have <D><H></H></D>

Comment: See my edit, I think. The code as-is will give you `<D>\n<H/>\n</D>`, the modification would give you `<H/>`. I added a few comments to my code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parser that's already written.

Don't use one that you've rolled yourself, you're just asking to make a problem for yourself.

Comment: It's not a parser it's regular expressions, it just gets everything between the <D>'s and </D>